# Copy/write out all actually used package commands

Tags: python, testing, import

Let's say we have written many lines of code, maybe even in different files/modules. Now for testing (e.g. compatibility with a new version) we wanted to extract all commands of imports that have been actually used. Is there an easy way to do this (some already existing export function of a python IDE instead of writing them out by hand or programming to export them from a text version of the code file)? 
Example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

justnormalpythoncommand1
justnormalpythoncommand2

np.numpycommand1()
np.numpycommand2()

plt.matplotlibcommand1()

justnormalpythoncommand1

plt.matplotlibcommand2()

np.numpycommand3()

plt.matplotlibcommand3()
```

I am interested in an output similar to:

np commands to test:

```
np.numpycommand1()
np.numpycommand2()
np.numpycommand3()
```

plt commands to test:

```
plt.matplotlibcommand1()
plt.matplotlibcommand2()
plt.matplotlibcommand3()
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the inspect module.  It's used to get various information about the functions or methods in a module.  Here's a link to a how-to:

[inspect – Inspect live objects](https://pymotw.com/2/inspect/)